# Onegaishimasu meanings, reply and when to use

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech

*Onegaishimasu* is used by Japanese people a lot. What does it mean, in what context is it used, and how do I respond to this?

I found on the web that it means:

> Please take care of me.
>
> I am in your care.
>
> Do me this favor.

Comment: Cf. [bitte](http://extinctosaur.tumblr.com/post/33594753818/bitte).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it as the word ¨please¨ in English. If someone says おねがいしますね to you, they are always asking you to do something or expect something from you.

For example if a friend tells me that she likes chocolates and I say, I will buy for you. Then she might say, お願いします。 meaning, ¨please do¨, or ¨that would be great¨.

If you want to imply that the other person should actually do something because it's important, you can use おねがいしますよ which is a bit stronger.
For example I can ask my brother to pick up my kids from school tomorrow and I can at the end of the sentence say おねがいしますよ as a way to emphasise that he shouldn't forget this. I think this is the example of what you posted in your question ¨Please take care of me.¨

You can respond to the おねがいします as どうぞ ¨here you go¨ when they are asking you for something, or you can answer はい、わかりました ”understood” when it's an important request that you will do later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice explanation..  ありがとうございます！！！

Answer (score 2):

If you translate literally, onegai means request, shimasu means to do(polite).
So it's basically a polite way to make a request.
As you said, it is used a lot and in many context.

I could make a list of way to use it, but it would be quite a long one.

those 2 might be more adequate for the expression "yoroshiku onegaishimasu".

> Please take care of me.
>   I am in your care.